# How can I recreate TextBlock style with multibinding in code?

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, data-binding

Here's what I have as XAML code for a `TextBlock` for a WPF app. This is working just fine with my current databinding.

```
<TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="Black" FontSize="32" FontWeight="Bold">
                                <TextBlock.Style>
                                    <Style TargetType="TextBlock" BasedOn="{StaticResource InvisibleTextBlock}">
                                        <Style.Triggers>
                                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding MatchModel.TeamARightEnd}" Value="True">
                                                <Setter Property="Text">
                                                    <Setter.Value>
                                                        <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0} - {1}">
                                                            <Binding Path="TeamBScore"/>
                                                            <Binding Path="TeamAScore"/>
                                                        </MultiBinding>
                                                    </Setter.Value>
                                                </Setter>
                                            </DataTrigger>
                                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding MatchModel.TeamARightEnd}" Value="False">
                                                <Setter Property="Text">
                                                    <Setter.Value>
                                                        <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0} - {1}">
                                                            <Binding Path="TeamAScore"/>
                                                            <Binding Path="TeamBScore"/>
                                                        </MultiBinding>
                                                    </Setter.Value>
                                                </Setter>
                                            </DataTrigger>
                                        </Style.Triggers>
                                    </Style>
                                </TextBlock.Style>
                            </TextBlock>
```

Now I need to create several of these textblocks dynamically and add them to a `StackPanel`. I successfully recreated it thus:

```
TextBlock scoretextblock = new()
            {
                Name = "TextBlockScore" + i,
                HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center,
                VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center,
                Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black),
                FontSize = 32,
                FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold,
            };
            scoretextblock.Style = new()
            {
                TargetType = typeof(TextBlock),
                Triggers =
                {
                    new DataTrigger
                    {
                        Value = true,
                        Binding = new Binding("MatchModel.TeamARightEnd"),
                        Setters =
                        {
                            new Setter
                            {
                                Property = TextBlock.TextProperty,
                                Value = new Binding("TeamAScore") + " - " + new Binding("TeamBScore")
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            };
```

During execution, I successfully find the above `TextBlock`s and can change the datacontext. However, the required result displayed is blank.
Does anyone have any idea what I'm doing wrong? Or is there a way to recreate these `TextBlock` dynamically in XAML itself?

Thanks!!

Comment: Without a proper [mcve], it's impossible to say for sure what might be wrong. But you seem to be going about this all the wrong way. You should be declaring a `<DataTemplate.../>` element in XAML with the `<TextBlock.../>` you want, and then bind a view model for that template in the appropriate part of the UI layout. Any time you are instantiating UI elements in code instead of just declaring them in XAML, it's almost certain you've made a mistake.

Comment: Ah good idea. I was hoping to have some kind of template that could easily be applied to the dynamically created textblocks

Comment: Wait. Creating a `DataTemplate` and applying it to the TextBlock style does not work. I'm getting "has an incompatible type' error.

Comment: Templates aren't applied to styles. They are implicitly used by WPF for content presenters bound to specific instances of a view model type for which the template is declared. You should do some reading on templating in XAML. For example, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/data-templating-overview

Comment: Especially this section: [Styling and Templating an ItemsControl](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/data-templating-overview?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8#styling-and-templating-an-itemscontrol). You would use an ItemsControl which by default has a StackPanel as ItemsPanel. Use your DataTemplate as its ItemTemplate.

Comment: At a minimum, you have XAML and C # differences in setting the binding in the trigger.
In XAML, you specify a MultiBinding, and in C #, you specify a Binding concatenation converted to strings.
The result will be difficult to predict.
Create (once in field) a MultiBinding instance, assign a value to its `StringFormat = "{0} - {1}"` property, and add two Binding instances to the Bindings property.
Then you can assign this MultiBinding instance in your trigger.

Comment: Thank you all! Very nice pointers. I've indeed created an `ItemsControl` and `DataTemplate` which handles the dynamic `TextBlock`s nicely.

Answer (score 1):

The `Value` of the `Setter` should be set to a `MultiBinding`, e.g.:

```
DataTrigger dataTrigger = new DataTrigger() { Value = true, Binding = new Binding("MatchModel.TeamARightEnd") };
MultiBinding multiBinding = new MultiBinding()
{
    StringFormat = "{0} - {1}"
};
multiBinding.Bindings.Add(new Binding("TeamAScore"));
multiBinding.Bindings.Add(new Binding("TeamBScore"));
dataTrigger.Setters.Add(new Setter() { Property = TextBlock.TextProperty, Value = multiBinding });

Style style = new Style() { TargetType = typeof(TextBlock) };
style.Triggers.Add(dataTrigger);

TextBlock scoretextblock = new TextBlock()
{
    Name = "TextBlockScore" + i,
    HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center,
    VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center,
    Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black),
    FontSize = 32,
    FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold,
    Style = Style
};
```

Comment: Thank you but I've moved everything to ItemsControl and using DataTemplates there as suggested in the comments of the original question

Comment: Well, this answers your original question. Please accept it to close the thread.

Answer (score 0):

After having tried out the several suggestions, here's what I went with:

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="test" d:DataContext="{x:Static local:LiveScoreDesignDataContext.PreviousGamesSampleData}" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Foreground="Black" FontSize="32" FontWeight="Bold">
                                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                        <UniformGrid Rows="1"/>
                                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <Grid>
                                            <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                                                <TextBlock.Style>
                                                    <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                                                        <Style.Triggers>
                                                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding TeamARightEnd}" Value="True">
                                                                <Setter Property="Text">
                                                                    <Setter.Value>
                                                                        <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0} - {1}">
                                                                            <Binding Path="TeamBScore"/>
                                                                            <Binding Path="TeamAScore"/>
                                                                        </MultiBinding>
                                                                    </Setter.Value>
                                                                </Setter>
                                                            </DataTrigger>
                                                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding TeamARightEnd}" Value="False">
                                                                <Setter Property="Text">
                                                                    <Setter.Value>
                                                                        <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0} - {1}">
                                                                            <Binding Path="TeamAScore"/>
                                                                            <Binding Path="TeamBScore"/>
                                                                        </MultiBinding>
                                                                    </Setter.Value>
                                                                </Setter>
                                                            </DataTrigger>
                                                        </Style.Triggers>
                                                    </Style>
                                                </TextBlock.Style>
                                            </TextBlock>
                                            <Border x:Name="brd" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" BorderThickness="0,0,2,0" BorderBrush="Black"/>
                                        </Grid>
                                        <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                                            <DataTrigger Value="True">
                                                <DataTrigger.Binding>
                                                    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource LastItemConverter}">
                                                        <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}" />
                                                        <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}"/>
                                                        <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}" Path="Items.Count"/>
                                                    </MultiBinding>
                                                </DataTrigger.Binding>
                                                <Setter TargetName="brd" Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />
                                            </DataTrigger>
                                        </DataTemplate.Triggers>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                            </ItemsControl>
```

Here's what it looks like:
[image: Image sample with sample data of 2 scores]